# How to make art work fill a custom painted border shape in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a custom shape of a crooked square for music artwork images, now I'm trying to make the image fill it completely whilst not leaking out of it.

[image]

I tried using a stack, but it is bugging the painted square and the image still would leak and not fill it completely.

> SizedBox(
> width: 50,
> height: 50,
> child: CustomPaint(
> painter: ImperfectRectangleBorder(strokeColor: Colors.white),
> child: QueryArtworkWidget(//from on_audio_query package
> artworkBorder: BorderRadius.zero,
> artworkFit: BoxFit.fill,
> id: item.data![index].id,
> type: ArtworkType.AUDIO,
> ),
> ),
> ),

```dart
class ImperfectRectangleBorder extends CustomPainter {
  final Color strokeColor;
  ImperfectRectangleBorder({this.strokeColor = Colors.white});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..color = strokeColor
      ..strokeWidth = 4.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, -5);
    path.lineTo(size.width * (0.2), size.height + 10);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - 5);
    path.lineTo(size.height * (0.8), -1);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you can  use [Transform](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html)

Comment: draw image with frame on canvas and then apply https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/transform.html